# An equivalence relation iff G≈H, where G and H are groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, equivalence-relations

> **Problem** : Let $S$ be the relation G~H iff G is isomorphic to H.

Show reflexive, transitivity and symmetric.

First show G is automorphism, which will imply G~G. So the identity mapping gives us this automorphism.  So G~G. My question is, is this the right process for showing reflexiveness?

Now we show symmetry. Assume G is isomorphic to H. Thus there exists a mapping $\phi:G ->H$.  We must show H is isomorphic to G. Since $\phi$ is this mapping, consider $\phi^{-1}.$ This is a bijection since $\phi$ is a bijection. How do I show it is homomorphic?

Finally show its transitive. This I have done in a previous problem.

This is different than the duplicate as suggested because previously I had done it incorrectly. I know now I must do it this way.

Comment: What are $G$ and $H$ here? Graphs, groups, rings, structures...?

Comment: groups, my bad. I fixed it in the title

Comment: @Jack: Don't try to trick us. Duplicates will just get closed.

Comment: but I was totally wrong on that one so Im trying it a different way. Thats not the right way to do it.  This is a completely different thing

Comment: @Jack: You can always Comment or Edit a previous Question you've posted, and saying "This is a completely different thing" in a Comment here seems disingenuous.  The Question is the same, even if you had done it incorrectly before (and you've had the benefit of Answers to the original version).  See the Help Center FAQ for more information about why duplicates will be closed, with links to where the Answers have already been given.

Comment: The "set" of all groups is not really a set, is it? I mean, it is a proper class.

Answer (score 0):

If $\phi$ is an isomorphism, we have $\phi(a)\phi(b)=\phi(ab)$. Therefore, taking $a=\phi^{-1}(u)$ and $b=\phi^{-1}(v)$ for any $u$ and $v$, we deduce that $uv=\phi(\phi^{-1}(u)\phi^{-1}(v))$, or $\phi^{-1}(uv)=\phi^{-1}(u)\phi^{-1}(v)$. In other words, $\phi^{-1}$ is an isomorhism.

Comment: what is an edge?

Comment: I assumed you mean graph isomorhisms as your tags indicate.

Comment: my bad wrong tag.

Comment: Corrected, now it answers the question on groups.

Comment: am I right on any part of how to go about doing this by suggesting what mappings?

Comment: The rest of your proof seems OK to me.